# SQL Server - return count of json array items in sql server column across multiple rows

Tags: sql-server

Using SQL Server 2019, I have data in a table with the following columns:

```
id, alias, value
```

The `value` column contains json in this format:

```
[
    {
        "num": 1,
        "description": "test 1"
    },
    {
        "num": 2,
        "description": "test 2"
    },
        {
        "num": 3,
        "description": "test 2"
    }
]
```

I want to get a count of "num" items within the json for each row in my SQL table.

For example query result should look like

```
id   CountOfNumFromValueColumn
------------------------------
 1             3
```

Update - The SQL below works with the above json and gives results in the above format

```
SELECT id, count(Num) AS CountOfNumFromValueColumn
FROM MyTable
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON ([value], N'$')
  WITH (
    num int)
WHERE ISJSON([value]) > 0 
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: *"there is no result at all."* 2 Reasons: You're looking for the node `$.num.num`, which doesn't exist, and 2 your [JSON isn't valid](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5822ec9ce74f7608264db4d913ff45bc) (so the entire row is being filtered out).

Comment: Just corrected the json in the example and think I've got it working.  thanks for the prompt @Larnu

Comment: Note tat the above JSON is still not valid. There should be a double quote after both `"test 2`s. If you fix that, and remove `, N'$.num'` from the `OPENSJON` call, this works. These all, in truth, look like typographical errors to me.

Comment: @Larnu - if you turn your comment into an answer, I can mark as correct.

Comment: I VTC'd to close as a typographical error.

Comment: Well my actual problem was not typographical, it was a complete misunderstanding about json path syntax.  Didn't realise that using $ would pick up all the root items and allow me to count. Now the 'penny has dropped' so thank you :)